# Selecting part of array in jsrender

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsrender

tell me how to make a selection of only part of the data in jsrender

For example i have that array:

```
сatlist = [
{
    id: "1",
    title: "Category 1",
        products: [
        { name: "Child doc 1" },
        { name: "Child doc 2" }
    ]

},
    {
    id: "2",
    title: "Category 2",
        products: [
        { name: "Child doc 3" },
        { name: "Child doc4" }
      ]

    }
];
```

How display in the template only child documents which id category 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <div id="peopleList"></div>

<script id="personTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  <label>id:</label> {{:id}}<br/>
<label>name:</label> {{:title}}<br/>
{{if id==2}}
{{for products }}
<label>product name:</label> {{:name}}<br/>
{{/for}}
{{/if}}
</script>

var myTemplate = $.templates("#personTmpl");

var people = [
{
    id: "1",
    title: "Category 1",
        products: [
        { name: "Child doc 1" },
        { name: "Child doc 2" }
    ]

},
    {
    id: "2",
    title: "Category 2",
        products: [
        { name: "Child doc 3" },
        { name: "Child doc4" }
      ]

    }
];

var html = myTemplate.render(people);

$("#peopleList").html(html);
```

if you want to exclude any thing you can do it i place all code you can exclude things by your own hope it ll helps you.